# Validation according to Facebook 'page liked' using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have to add a Facebook like button to an existing form for an app built in CodeIgniter.

The form cannot be valid unless the user has clicked like (horrible, I know.) using the official FB like button code. I'm not used to code igniter & my PHP knowledge is limited. Any help extending my code much appreciated.

currently i have the following:

```
    public function likeGate( ) {

    if( $this->hasUserPerms() != true )
    {
        $this->tplVars['js_footer'] = 'app.fb.geifPerms();';
    }
    return false;
}
```

for the validation:

```
    public function getPostDetails()
{
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $errors = array();
    $fields = array(
        'liked' => function( $value ){

            if( $this->tplVars['perms'] == false || $this->tplVars['likes'] == false )
            {
            return false;
            }
            else
            {
            return true;
            }

        },

        'full_name' => function( $value ){

            if( strlen( $value ) > 5 && preg_match('/^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąćęèéêëìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð ,.\'-]+$/iu', $value ) == 1 )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        },

        'email' => function( $value )
        {
            if( preg_match( '/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/', $value ) )
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        'terms' => function( $value )
        {
            if( $value !== 'agreed' )
            {
                return false;   
            }

            return true;
        },

        'card_number' => function( $value )
        {
            if( !empty( $value ) && ( strlen( $value ) < 11 || strlen( $value ) > 12 )  ) // Maybe add further card validation
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    );

    foreach( $fields as $key => $field )
    {
        if( ( !isset( $_POST[$key] ) && $key != 'card_number' ) ) {
            $errors[$key] = 'This is a required field'; 

        } else if( isset( $_POST[$key] ) && $field($_POST[$key]) == false ) {
            $errors[$key] = 'Invalid value, please correct it and try again.';  
        }
    }

    if( !empty( $errors ) )
    {
        $return = array( 'success' => false, 'errors' => $errors );

    }
    else if( $this->userHasSubmission() )
    {
        $return = array('success' => false, 'errors' => array( 'full_name' => 'User already has completed a submission'));

    }
    else
    {
        $data   = array_merge( $_POST, array('fbid' => $this->facebook->getUser()));
        $return = array('success' => true, 'errors' => array());

        $this->load->model('Henhouse_model');
        $this->Henhouse_model->insertRow( $data );
    }


    echo json_encode( $return );
    exit;
}
```

user permissions:

```
    private function hasUserPerms()
{
    if( isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) )
    {
        $this->facebook->setAccessToken( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
    }
    else if( isset( $_GET['code'] ) )
    {
        $this->facebook->setAccessToken($_GET['code']);     
    }

    $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();

    // check if we have valid user
    if( $fbid )
    {
        try
        {
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $fb_user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
        }
        catch ( FacebookApiException $e ) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private function userLikesPage()
{
    if( !$this->hasUserPerms() )
    {
        return false;
    }

    $like_status = $this->facebook->api('/me/likes/140681946901');

    if( isset( $like_status ) && $like_status['data'] == true )
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for permissions? If you're not, that will only work one time. You can know programaticaaly when a user liked something because it fires an event, but without user permissions you can't know if the user already liked your form the second time is coming to your website.

Comment: Thanks For getting back, I have now included the code for the permissions above. Any idea how to validate the like here?

Comment: are you using the facebook javascript SDK? javascript sdk allows you to listen for the like event. Basically you should have this flow, on the server side before loading the form view, you must check if the user already likes your page, if he doesn't, load a view with the like button, then using the javascript sdk listen for the event "edge.create", then on the response of that function just refresh the page or do an ajax request and retrieve the form. It's easier to validate the like before presenting the form to the user.

Comment: I am already using the SDK but can't seem to get the javascript right for it validate once you hit submit.